# How to correctly handle this Date field mapping using JdbcTemplate into a Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, rowmapper

it is pretty long time that I am not using Spring and I am finding some difficulties with this JdbcTemplate row mapper mapping a date field.

I try to explain my situation in details.

On my database (MariaDB) I have this table named **TREND002**:

```
+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Time_Stamp      | datetime | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Time_Stamp_ms   | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Sensor001DV     | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Sensor002DV     | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Sensor003DV     | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
..............................................................
..............................................................
..............................................................
| Sensor00NDV     | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

**NOTE-1:** the **Time_Stamp** field contains value as **2010-10-22 16:50:12**

Then I have this DTO class mapping the field of the previous table:

```
public class TrendDTO {

    private Date dateTime;
    private int timeStampMs;
    private String sensorValue;

    public TrendDTO() {
        super();
    }

    public TrendDTO(Date dateTime, int timeStampMs, String sensorValue) {
        super();
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.timeStampMs = timeStampMs;
        this.sensorValue = sensorValue;
    }

    public Date getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public int getTimeStampMs() {
        return timeStampMs;
    }

    public void setTimeStampMs(int timeStampMs) {
        this.timeStampMs = timeStampMs;
    }

    public String getSensorValue() {
        return sensorValue;
    }

    public void setSensorValue(String sensorValue) {
        this.sensorValue = sensorValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TrendDTO [dateTime=" + dateTime + ", timeStampMs=" + timeStampMs + ", sensorValue=" + sensorValue + "]";
    }

}
```

Basially in this DTO class I have:

- A **Date** field mapping the **datetime** field of my table.
- An **int** field mapping the Time_Stamp_ms field of my table.
- A **String** field mapping the value of a specific **SensorXXXDV** field of the table (I know that from a relational database point of view this is ugly as hell...but I inherited the project and at the moment I can't change).

Finnally I have a **repository** class in which there is this method:

```
@Override
public List<TrendDTO> findTrendListBySensorName(String tableName, String columnName) {

    List<TrendDTO> result = null;

    String RETRIEVE_TREND_BY_SENSOR_NAME = "SELECT Time_Stamp, Time_Stamp_ms, Sensor240DV FROM Delphys.TREND003";

    //result = jdbcTemplate.query(RETRIEVE_TREND_BY_SENSOR_NAME, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(TrendDTO.class));

    result =  jdbcTemplate.query(
            RETRIEVE_TREND_BY_SENSOR_NAME,
            (rs, rowNum) ->

                    new TrendDTO(
                            new java.util.Date(rs.getTimestamp("Time_Stamp").getTime()),
                            rs.getInt("Time_Stamp_ms"),
                            String.valueOf(rs.getDouble(columnName))
                    )
    );

    return result;
}
```

It works fine but doing in this way I obtain a list of **TrendDTO** instances containing **dateTime** field values like this:

**dateTime=Fri Oct 22 16:50:12 PDT 2010**

The date is perfectly correct but I think that this is the wrong format. I have to return this DTO object in JSON format to a front end and I need a date in the format:

**2010-10-22 16:50:12**

I also tried to change my mapper code using this:

```
result =  jdbcTemplate.query(
                RETRIEVE_TREND_BY_SENSOR_NAME,
                (rs, rowNum) ->

                        new TrendDTO(
                                //new java.util.Date(rs.getTimestamp("Time_Stamp").getTime()),
                                rs.getTimestamp("Time_Stamp"),
                                rs.getInt("Time_Stamp_ms"),
                                String.valueOf(rs.getDouble(columnName))
                        )
        );
```

As you can see I am simply using **rs.getTimestamp("Time_Stamp")** but doing in this way I am obtaining a **dateTime** inizialization like this: **2010-10-22 16:50:12.0**

As you can see it end with a **.0** that should represents milliseconds that I don't want. Can I specify the format to avoid to put also this ending millisecond section?

Another possible approach to solve my problem (maybe the best solution) is: in this pretty horrible database table the millisecond information is contained into the **Time_Stamp_ms** column that, at the moment, is mapped with my **timeStampMs** DTO field.

Can I modify my previous code to encapsulate this information directly into the **dateTime** field of my DTO object?

I am absolutly not sure that with this syntax (is it a lambda expression?) this is possible. Can I do it using this syntax or have I to implement a row mapper class to implement this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

1. Don't use the old "Date" API anymore, use the newer (Java8+) **LocalDateTime instead**. Assuming you have a relatively recent JDBC driver, you can do this to get a LocalDateTime, it saves you a few strokes trying to convert your timestamp to a date.

   `LocalDateTime yourLocalDateTime = rs.getObject("Time_Stamp", LocalDateTime.class) ;`
2. You can format that LocalDateTime any way you want. To do that manually, you would use a **DateTimeFormatter**.

   `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String formatDateTime = yourLocalDateTime.format(formatter);`
3. Though if you are in a Spring Boot project and serializing to JSON, all you need to do is annotate your DTO with the **@JsonFormat** annotation:

   `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
   private LocalDateTime myLocalDateTime;`